# (Fullcalendar 4 VueJs) Adding custom element inside Calendar Header

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Please take a look at my approach and tell me is it a good/correct way to add a complex DOM element inside Fullcalendar header.

```
   viewSkeletonRender(info){

    this.$refs.fullCalendar.$el.querySelector('.fc-header-toolbar').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
      <div class="event_create-wrap">
        <div class="event_create-btn">
          <div class="event_create-btn-left">
            Create
          </div>
          <div class="event_create-dropdown">
            <button class="event_create-btn-dropdown" @click="eventDropdownClicked">
              <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M111 13.8822L3.62734 8.39658C3.23555 8.01742 3.23555 7.40432 3.62734 7.0292L4.5693 6.11762C4.96109 5.73846 5.59462 5.73846 5.98224 6.11762L10.0002 10.006L14.0181 6.11762C14.4099 5.73846 15.0434 5.73846 15.431 6.11762L16.373 7.0292C16.7648 7.40836 16.7648 8.02146 16.373 8.39658L10.7045 13.8822C10.3211 14.2614 9.68756 14.2614 9.29578 13.8822Z" fill="white"/>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="event_create-btn-dropdown-content" :class="{show: isEventListShown}">
              <a href="">1</a>
              <a href="">2</a>
              <a href="">3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
  }
```

I am using "viewSkeletonRender" hook but i am not really sure that using "insertAdjacentHTML" is good, since i've used it first time.

1. I can't use AppendChild because i need to add so many html code there and it is difficult to create all html objects step by step (what if i need to add 100 html tags...) .
2. I can't use innerHtml because it will remove all what i have in fc-header-toolbar.

And as i understand i can't bind any VueJs props and methods to this HTML with this approach because i add this html as vanila Js.

Thank you for your advice.